# Are Windows Containers unavailable on Windows 10 Education?

Tags: docker, windows-10, containers

According to [Microsoft's guide on Windows Containers on Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10) and [the OS requirements page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deployment/system_requirements) you need Windows 10 Professional or Enterprise to install the Windows Containers feature. I have Windows 10 Education, which is [built on Enterprise with some additions aimed at users in education](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/05/13/introducing-windows-10-editions/).

When I tried to install the feature, I got an error:

```
PS C:\Users\Erik> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name containers is unknown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers -All
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

Is the Windows Containers feature unavailable on Windows 10 Education?

#### Update

It appears the containers are not *yet* available for Education [[source 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jcorioland/2016/05/31/create-and-run-hyper-v-containers-using-docker-on-windows-10-desktop/#comment-305),[source 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0befc4af-ba94-4b83-b25d-209e6828a02c/container-feature-on-windows-10-insider-build-14390-is-not-available?forum=windowscontainers)]. Is there a way to know when updates roll out for the various editions and features of Windows 10?